# Debugging ADT Eclipse Plugin Install

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I've installed the Android SDK and the ADT plugin, but Android doesn't show up in the Window>Preferences... dialog.

I'm running Galileo. If I go to the Installation Details part of the About Eclipse dialog, it says that I have 0.9.6 of Android DDMS and Android Development Tools. I can run adb from the command line. I tried going around the uninstall/reinstall loop once.

I'm on Windows Vista. I also have 2.7.7 of the Scala plugin installed, but I tried uninstalling that.

Any ideas on what I should try next? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your eclipse installation running from the "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)" folder?
This was my case and I had this particular problem and a few more.

What I did was to place a fresh copy of Eclipse in a different folder (e.g. c:\dev), launch it and to install the Android Plug-in using the Eclipse Update and it seems to work fine now.

I did not need to download again the Android SDK.

Comment: I uninstalled everything and reinstalled in different directories like you suggested. Now everything seems to be working fine. Perhaps it's related to that old problem with installing the JVM in a directory with a space in the path? Anyways, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing a dependency. What you're describing happened to me once (I can't remember for sure, but I think it was with adt).

From http://developer.android.com/intl/de/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing:

> Note that there are features of ADT
>   that require some optional Eclipse
>   components (for example, WST). If you
>   encounter an error when installing
>   ADT, your Eclipse installion might not
>   include these components. For
>   information about how to quickly add
>   the necessary components to your
>   Eclipse installation, see the
>   troubleshooting topic ADT Installation
>   Error: "requires plug-in
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui".

Comment: WST didn't seem to do it, but this looks like a promising direction. I'll check through other dependencies tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Seems to be related to where Eclipse is installed, the path should not contain spaces, like David suggested.

I installed a fresh copy of Eclipse to c:\Dev and installed the ADT. Now everything works fine.